# Expanded div overlapping its parent - z-index issue

Tags: css, expandable

I need to display a collection of tiles (laid out using flexbox), where each tile has an "expando" child that - on hover - is supposed to expand beyond the parent limit. This part works, except for z-index. This doesn't surprise me after all, as every tile make its own z-index stacking context. I am just lost of ideas how to solve it.

I would really need to make these tiles and their children self-contained (to be later extracted into an angular component).

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="plate">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum vero necessitatibus possimus praesentium, eos magnam mollitia doloribus adipisci, nam et, accusamus vel pariatur ipsam dolore iusto officia amet veritatis eveniet.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="plate">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum vero necessitatibus possimus praesentium, eos magnam mollitia doloribus adipisci, nam et, accusamus vel pariatur ipsam dolore iusto officia amet veritatis eveniet.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="plate">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum vero necessitatibus possimus praesentium, eos magnam mollitia doloribus adipisci, nam et, accusamus vel pariatur ipsam dolore iusto officia amet veritatis eveniet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3em;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.plate {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 190px;
  color: green;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.holder:hover .plate {
  display: flex;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hk149512/)

Comment: Why is z-index an issue https://jsfiddle.net/hk149512/2/ ? change it for the holder not for the plate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set z-index on .holder:hover.

```
.holder:hover {
   z-index:10;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hk149512/3/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the `z-index` for the holder element on `:hover`, just add to your code:

```
.holder:hover {
  z-index:10
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3em;
}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.plate {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid limegreen;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  width: 190px;
  color: green;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.holder:hover {
  z-index:10
}

.holder:hover .plate {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="plate">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum vero necessitatibus possimus praesentium, eos magnam mollitia doloribus adipisci, nam et, accusamus vel pariatur ipsam dolore iusto officia amet veritatis eveniet.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="plate">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum vero necessitatibus possimus praesentium, eos magnam mollitia doloribus adipisci, nam et, accusamus vel pariatur ipsam dolore iusto officia amet veritatis eveniet.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="holder">
    <div class="plate">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum vero necessitatibus possimus praesentium, eos magnam mollitia doloribus adipisci, nam et, accusamus vel pariatur ipsam dolore iusto officia amet veritatis eveniet.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```